# Wincap Msn messenger, yahoo messenger, google talk

Tags: yahoo, google-talk, msn

Does someone know how to use Wincap(or other library) to see messages sent from and to Msn messenger, yahoo messenger, google talk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) is what you want for this.

Some info on on their wiki:

- MSN Messenger: http://wiki.wireshark.org/MSNMS
- Yahoo: http://wiki.wireshark.org/YMSG

Google Talk is an implementation of Jabber, but I believe it is encrypted, so I'm not sure you will be able to read much of that.

Comment: I imagine he wants a programmatic/api solution.

Comment: I guess.  But you are going to want to understand what you are capturing first, Wireshark is a good example of how to use WinPcap if nothing else :)

Comment: I now see that Winpcap cannot be used for commercial software unless i get the pro version. Any other solutions? TY.